# Weird behaviour of .NET Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

MSDN says for `GC.Collect()`

> All objects, regardless of how long they have been in memory, are
>   considered for collection; **however, objects that are referenced in
>   managed code are not collected**. Use this method to force the system
>   to try to reclaim the maximum amount of available memory.

So I would expect that a Child class that is still referenced in a Parent class is not collected before the Parent is collected.

But the weird thing is that it is MOSTLY collected BEFORE the parent is collected. This does not make any sense to me.

I compile the following code on VS2010 and run it on framework 4.0.
What I get is this:

[image: Garbage Collector Test Code]

```
using System;

namespace GarbageCollector
{
    class Child
    {
        public bool bInUse = true;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child finished by Parent.");
            bInUse = false;
        }

        ~Child()
        {
            bInUse = false;
        }
    }

    class Parent
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        ~Parent()
        {
            if (!child.bInUse)
                Console.WriteLine("Finalizing Child that is still in use in a Parent!");

            child.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                     Parent P = new Parent();
                }
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain me what is going on here?

---

**EDIT:**

I already found out how to solve the problem. If you want to access class members in the Finalizer of your class this can be a problem if these members themself also have a Finalizer. In this case the members may already be dead before the Finalizer of your class can access them because the GarbageCollector destroys them in ANY order. (Child before Parent or Child after Parent)

BUT if you access class members that do NOT have an own finalizer this problem does not appear.

So if you want to store for example a list of handles in your class and you want to close these handles in the Finalizer then make sure that this list class does NOT have an own Finalizer, otherwise your handles may be gone before you can close them!

Comment: the garbage collector is pretty smart - likely its detecting that the `list` isn't being used so it cleans that up.

Comment: I removed the ArrayList. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Have you enabled optimizations?

Comment: you should not be modifying anything except doing cleanup in finalizers. you aren't guaranteed of anything in them.

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, take a leaf from @D3C34C34D's book and consider cloning the project, and tweaking with configurations/optimizations until you find out what may or may not be injecting the behavior.

Comment: Are you running in Release mode from the command line (not via VS)? The GC acts differently when a debugger is attached.

Comment: Finalization != Collection. Nothing odd is happening. You are assuming that during GC each object is checked, finalized then collected. However that would be highly inefficient; instead the GC checks and marks each item for collection, then finalizes all of them, then collects all of them.

Comment: You have confused finalization with collection. They are not at all the same thing. You may benefit from reading my series "everything you know is wrong" if you want to learn what other falsehoods you believe about finalization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I would expect that a Child class that is still referenced in a Parent class is not collected before the Parent is collected.

That's not a true assumption.  The GC is free to collect any object so long as it can prove that the object is no longer accessible from any code that will run at any point in the future.  It is *allowed* to collect any object at that point, but it is free to collect, or leave, any of the objects meeting that condition.  If an object references another, but neither are rooted or accessible from any rooted object, the GC is free to delete them in any order, or even to delete the child and not the parent.

It's also worth noting that your code is showing nothing.  The finalizer for the object *may* be run at any point between when it's eligible for collect and when it actually is collected.  even if the finalizer for both are run, the order that the finalizers run in isn't guarenteed to be the order that the objects themselves are collected in.

Of course, in practice, odds are *very* high that both objects will actually be collected at *exactly* the same time, unless one of the objects has existed for much longer than the other.  The GC runs by considering all objects (in a given tier) as "dead", and then copying those that are still "alive" into a new section, leaving all that aren't copied to be overridden whenever something happens to need that memory, so if both objects are in the same GC tier (which is probable) then the memory for both locations is able to be overridden at *exactly the same instant in time*.  As for when that memory is *actually* overridden, it'd be super hard to even find out (if it even ever is overridden).

So in the end the entire concept behind the quoted expectation isn't really a sensible premise, on many different levels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So this means that I cannot write a code in a Finalizer that accesses any of the classes members because at that moment they may already be dead - some or all of them. I did not know that.

Comment: @Elmue That's literally the opposite of what I said.  That said, you still shouldn't be accessing the managed properties of the object, for a lot of other reasons, but not because it could have been collected, because it's not actually able to be fully collected until after the finalizer has finished.

Comment: How is it the opposite? You wrote "... the GC is free to delete them in any order...." which means that the Child may be dead before the Parent. So the Child may already be inaccessible in Parent.Finalize(). Please read my EDIT.

Comment: @Elmue The objects can be finalized in any order, and they can be actually collected in any order, but the child cannot be collected before the parent has been finalized (precisely because it is accessible through the execution of managed code through the finalizer).  Again, finalization and collection are two completely separate things, you still seem to be treating them as the same thing; they're not at all.